# Long list selector sorting is not working

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I've got two clear LongListSelectors - without any modification, just dragged from toolbox and changed name.
I'm using code below to fill them (one of them needs to be sorted):

```
closestList.ItemsSource = spots;    
allList.ItemsSource = spots.OrderBy(x => x.name).ToList();
```

The first list is working fine, but the second one is empty - there is no error. When I change the second line to: `allList.ItemsSource = spots;` it's working fine.
What is wrong with that sort?

Comment: Oh, sorry - spots is an ObservableCollection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment that you're writing the code that you have, `spots` is empty and contains no items.  When you define the source of the data as a reference to `spots` it is capable of recognizing when items are added (if `spots` is an observable collection, which it does appear to be) which means that in the future, when items get added to `spots`, the UI will be updated.

Your second snippet isn't setting the data source as a reference to `spots`, but rather as a *copy* of the collection at that instant in time.  At that instant in time it's empty, and since the act of copying it has now divorced that data source from `spots` it will never be notified when items are added to `spots`, so it *stays* empty.

Comment: You're right. I've added order to method that is filling spots with data, and it works fine.